# Java ScheduledExecutorService - overlap in cycles

Tags: java, scheduledexecutorservice

My ScheduledExecutorService is intended to run every 30 minutes - every start and middle of the hour (09:00 , 09:30 etc..). This is set up and runs fine when the task is less than 30 minutes long.

If during one instance of the cycles the execution time is more than 30 minutes what should I expect:

1. multiple cycles running at the same time (example - the one started at 09:00 may finish at       09:40 but another cycle kicks in at 09:30 and these 2 are running in parallel)
2. the entire every 30 minutes execution scheme will now move by the additional execution 
    time of the long cycle (example - the one started at 09:00 may finish at 09:40 the one  that was supposed to start at 09:30 will start immediately at 09:40).

Many thanks !

Comment: The exact behaviour depends on how it is scheduled. Can you show us some code, please? I would expect it to behave like in your Point 2. What is your wanted behaviour if the Task is executing longer than the cycle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two options for scheduling repeating tasks: [`scheduleAtFixedRate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate-java.lang.Runnable-long-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) and [`scheduleWithFixedDelay`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleWithFixedDelay-java.lang.Runnable-long-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-). I'm assuming you are doing the former, because that's much easier to trigger every 30 minutes.

In which case, the Javadocs on this are quite clear:

> If any execution of this task takes longer than its period, then subsequent executions may start late, but will not concurrently execute.

So if your 09:30 task takes 33 minutes, your 10:00 task will slip by 3 minutes.

Comment: ... and if it takes 63 minutes, there will be 3 Tasks running in a row without any delay!